# Is it correct to say 'Do you know him in person?'

Tags: verbs

I came across a discussion on another forum where they are discussing different ways to ask if you actually know a person.

'Do you know him personally?

Did you meet him in person?

Do you know him in person?'

There's a debate going on as to whether 'Do you know him in person?' is correct English. One person stated that 'in person' requires an active verb [action verb; EA]. I understand action and stative verbs to some extent but I do not quite understand this. Do you agree with this person?

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lo-conoces-en-persona.3238389/#post-16711884

Comment: It's an odd construction. *In person* means being physically present, where the physical presence dominates the sense of what's being conveyed. On the other hand, *knowing* someone is not normally thought of as a purely physical activity (other than the obvious exception). So strictly-speaking, the phrasing works, but it might give the wrong impression.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. It's what I'd ask a kid about his or her Facebook friends: *do you know them (him/her) in person?*

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky. All the dictionaries I've checked in license the action verb / punctive usage, and [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-something-in-person) could actually be considered to restrict the phrase by adding a punctive verb:

> **do something in person**  ...
>
> to do something by going to a place or person rather than by writing,
>   telephoning, or sending someone else
>
> *You have to collect your tickets in person.*
>
> *I’ve talked to him on the telephone and in person.*

The [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-person) entry is not quite as prescriptive:

> **in person**
>
> by meeting with someone rather than talking on the phone, e-mailing,
>   or writing to the person:
>
> *You must apply for the license in person.*

though I'd say we can assume the 'to do something' here too.

[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+person) muddies the waters by adding the synonym 'personally':

> **in person**
>
> In one's physical presence; personally:
>
> *applied for the job in person.*

and of course 'personally' doesn't require a punctive verb: *I know her personally.* (stative) I'd consider this entry misleading.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-person) seems to give a tighter if not totally decisive definition, but adds a second sense (which, however, seems to require an action verb if not a punctive usage):

> **in person**
>
> a. actually present
>
> *the author will be there in person*
>
> b. without the help or intervention of others

And [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_person) again seems inconclusive (but note that all examples given have been with action verbs):

> **in person**
>
> With the personal presence or action of the individual specified.
>
> *he had to pick up his welfare cheque in person*

Google searches show that expressions like 'know him in person' are far from rare, but [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know+him+in+person%2Cknow+her+in+person%2Cknow+them+in+person%2Cknow+him+personally%2Cknow+her+personally%2Cknow+them+personally&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknow%20him%20in%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20her%20in%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20them%20in%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20him%20personally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20her%20personally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20them%20personally%3B%2Cc0) show that 'know him personally' etc are by far the more popular variants. They'd be my choice.